# How to make div sortable inside of a row class?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Well basically I have a container that I want to be able to sort all the divs inside of it :

```
<div class="container">
    <div id ="sortable" class="row ui-sortable">
    <div class="boxEncar">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?php zone_print("middle1") ; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?php zone_print("middle2") ; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?php zone_print("middle3") ; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's my call to `sortable` class:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#sortable').sortable();
});
```

The issue here is that the whole `container` get sortable while i just need `col-md-4` to be so! Any way I can achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: $(".col-md-4").sortable()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to select the parent of the sortable items!

```
jQuery('#sortable > .boxEncar').sortable();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use:

```
jQuery('#sortable').find('.col-md-4').sortable();
```

instead of:

```
jQuery('#sortable').sortable();
```

Comment: Yea sorry! but I forgot to mention that I already tried this but the divs doesn't get sorted!